# How to create a persistent view from a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe `df`, and would like to save it as a persistent view. Is that possible?

I tried to do the following:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")
spark.sql('CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM temp_view'))
```

And I got the following error message: 
"Not allowed to create a permanent view `my_view` by referencing a temporary view `temp_view`"

Comment: why you want to create a view again?

Comment: A persisted view requires a persisted table.

Comment: if you already have the dataframe...why not just cache it? df.cache, When you do register the table as a Temp View, the dataframe is still cached....and any subsequent spark.sql queries will be on the cached dataframe

Comment: The story is that I have a persisted table, and I want to append one row to it and save it back to the Hive. However, I thought it would be more space-efficient to save it as a view (as a view is a computation plan based on a table) than saving it as an another table.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26361) creating a permanent view that references a temporary view is disallowed. PySpark has also no methods that can create a persistent view, eg. `createTempView` and `createOrReplaceTempView`. You can create only a temporary view. For example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2]], ['col1', 'col2'])

df.createOrReplaceTempView('view1')

spark.sql(
    """
    CREATE TEMP VIEW view2 AS
    SELECT col1
    FROM view1
    """
)

spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM view2
    """
).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|   1|
|   1|
+----+
```

You can list available views:

```
spark.catalog.listTables()
```

Output:

```
[Table(name='view1', database=None, description=None, tableType='TEMPORARY', isTemporary=True),
 Table(name='view2', database=None, description=None, tableType='TEMPORARY', isTemporary=True)]
```